# If either there exists an Avesta book online in Avestan Script, or if you can transfer back romanized Avestan to Avestan Script reliably

Tags: orthography

I have been trying to find a copy of the Avesta in [Avestan Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avestan_alphabet), but the closest I could find was from http://www.avesta.org/avesta.html, which is written in some sort of romanized script:

> ashem vohû...(1 u 3). fravarâne mazdayasnô zarathushtrish vîdaêvô ahura-tkaêshô, hâvanêe ashaone ashahe rathwe ýasnâica vahmâica xshnaothrâica frasastayaêca, sâvanghêe vîsyâica ashaone ashahe rathwe ýasnâica vahmâica xshnaothrâica frasastayaêca.
>
> âthrô ahurahe mazdå puthrahe tava âtarsh puthra ahurahe mazdå xshnaothra ýasnâica vahmâica xshnaothrâica frasastayaêca.
>
> ...

I haven't completely scoured the site yet, but doing a brief look around I couldn't find what this "encoding" was, what the rules were. I would like to know (short of if you know of a link to a unicode Avesta document in Avestan Script) how to convert this romanized encoding back to Avestan Script, and if it would be exactly as original. I don't think it would be because there seems to be flexibility in whether or not you choose a ligature or not, etc, so there's probably no way to recreate the original Avestan Script version from this text. But who knows (hence my question). Wondering if you could clarify that, and otherwise point me to the rules for converting this to Avestan Script.

From [here](http://www.heritageinstitute.com/zoroastrianism/languages/#oral):

> The earliest known written text of the Avesta that has survived is a fragment of a 10th century CE Sogdian manuscript discovered in the 'Caves of a Thousand Buddhas' - a cliff wall near the city of Dunhuang, a town on the Silk Road in northwest China. The manuscript was written in the Sogdian using the Avestan script.

Answer (score 2):

For the complete text of the Avesta look here: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.217560/

Avestan script is not yet available on unicode, but they are working on it.

Comment: Isn't it encoded at U+10B00 onwards?

Comment: @Draconis is right; Avestan has the Unicode block from U+10B00 to U+10B3F. See [The Unicode Standard, sec. 10.7](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch10.pdf) for documentation.

Comment: @Draconis. Thanks, I didn't know this.